# Magento Order reports empty when using custom order status

Tags: php, magento, report

I'm trying to run an Order Report based on an Order Status which has been created.

The order status is called "Opportunity", so either the order comes through as "Pending" or "Opportunity" depending on a couple of things.

In the Orders list there's definitely orders which are opportunities and within the dates which I've specified for the report, however, it just says `No records found.`

I've done some research but I've not found a solution, I've tried mapping the Opportunity status to the "Complete" state rather than the "New", but this hasn't fixed it. I've also tried manually refreshing the statistics, but no luck there either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to submit Refresh lifetime statistics

Reports -> Refresh Statistics

[image]